# How to save image with the previous objectid

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have two activities and two ParseObjects respectively. In one activity I'm saving 3 strings and in another activity I'm saving Image to the ImageView. Its getting successfully saved to Parse.com but with different ObjectIds. I want the Image to be saved in other table. and then get the image based on the mobile number. I have searched the documentation referred in the Parse.com but not able to resolve this.

```
final ParseObject dataObject = new ParseObject("DataObject");
    dataObject.put("name", name);
    dataObject.put("mobilenumber", mobileNumber);
    dataObject.put("occupation", occup);
    dataObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
          public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                  // Success!
                   String objectId = dataObject.getObjectId();

                } else {
                  // Failure!
                }
              }
            });

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data successfully saved "+ objectId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This is the first activity. In the next activity I'm saving an image. I want the ObjectId but its says NULL everytime. Pls Help.

Comment: previous ParseObject means what ?

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy  Means the ParseObject I'm creating in the first activity. I need the data to save in the same ParseObject from the 2nd activity.

Comment: @Ruhi try sending and getting it with intent !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the mobile number with intent to your next activity like :

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

             progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoadImg.this, "",
                        "Saving Image...", true);

            try {
                image = readInFile(path);
            }
            catch(Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("picturePath.png", image);
            file.saveInBackground();    
            ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject("Image");
            imgupload.put("ImageFile", file);
            imgupload.put("Mobilenumber", mob);


            // Create the class and the columns
```

and in the activity you can fetch the mobile number from the intent like :

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Image");

            mobileNumber = mbltxt.getText().toString();
            query.whereEqualTo("Mobilenumber", mobileNumber);
            ob = query.find();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

You can send the three strings as a bundle from the first activity to the next(second) activity using `intent.putExtras(Bundle)` or `Intent.putExtra(String, String)` and then in the second activity, get the extras and then save the strings and the image together into a ParseObject. This will also reduce the number of API requests to Parse.